# Error: "Service invoked too many times for one day: scriptdb size."

Tags: google-apps-script

When trying to add objects to a ScriptDb store, get this error message:

> Service invoked too many times for one day: scriptdb size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached your quota for total ScriptDb size. The limit is per-user so the ScriptDb instance triggering this error could be small or even empty.

[Google Apps Script Script DB Quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#frequently_asked_questions)

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the total scriptdb size or the number of calls.

The error occurs when the item size is larger than 4 KB.

Comment: What makes you say that? When you say item, do you mean json object? We ran multiple tests and when you exceed your quota, this is the error and our objects were way less than 4 KB.